# Extract value from a string based on certain key value pairs

Tags: python, pandas, regex

I have some data I am pulling from JIRA that has data in the below format.

```
comment text is: [{'type': 'paragraph', 'content': [{'type': 'text', 'text': 'In conversation with the customer '}, {'type': 'mention', 'attrs': {'id': '04445152', 'text': '@Kev', 'accessLevel': ''}}, {'type': 'text', 'text': ' Text 123}]}]

comment text is: [{'type': 'paragraph', 'content': [{'type': 'text', 'text': '@xyz  Text abc'}]}]

comment text is: [{'type': 'paragraph', 'content': [{'type': 'mention', 'attrs': {'id': '3445343', 'text': '@Hey', 'accessLevel': ''}}, {'type': 'text', 'text': ' FYI'}]}]

comment text is:[{'content': [{'text': 'Output: ', 'type': 'text'}, {'type': 'hardBreak'}, {'type': 'hardBreak'}, {'text': "New Text goes here", 'type': 'text'}], 'type': 'paragraph'}]
```

I would like to extract all data that have key value of text and also concat if there are multiple such values in the same row. Given below is the expected output

Expected output:

```
In conversation with the customer @Kev Text 123

@xyz  Text abc

@Hey FYI

Output: New Text goes here
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your json values can be very complex and highly different among each other, you may use a positive lookbehind to spot your needed strings:

```
(?<='text': ['\"]).*?(?=['\"][},])
```

**Regex Explanation**:

- `(?<='text': ['\"])`: positive lookbehind matching `'text'`  and either a single or double quote
- `.*?`: any amount of characters, matched in a lazy fashion
- `(?=['\"][},])`: followed by a single or double quote, and either comma or closed brace.

While your Python code would be like:

```
import pandas as pd
import re

comments_df = pd.DataFrame([
    '''[{'type': 'paragraph', 'content': [{'type': 'text', 'text': 'In conversation with the customer '}, {'type': 'mention', 'attrs': {'id': '04445152', 'text': '@Kev', 'accessLevel': ''}}, {'type': 'text', 'text': ' Text 123'}]}]''',
    '''[{'type': 'paragraph', 'content': [{'type': 'text', 'text': '@xyz  Text abc'}]}]''',
    '''[{'type': 'paragraph', 'content': [{'type': 'mention', 'attrs': {'id': '3445343', 'text': '@Hey', 'accessLevel': ''}}, {'type': 'text', 'text': ' FYI'}]}]''',
    '''[{'content': [{'text': 'Output: ', 'type': 'text'}, {'type': 'hardBreak'}, {'type': 'hardBreak'}, {'text': "New Text goes here", 'type': 'text'}], 'type': 'paragraph'}]'''
], columns=['string'])

pattern = r'''(?<='text': ['\"]).*?(?=['\"][},])'''
print(comments_df['string'].str.findall(pattern).str.join(''))
```

**Output**:

```
0    In conversation with the customer @Kev Text 123
1                                     @xyz  Text abc
2                                           @Hey FYI
3                         Output: New Text goes here
Name: string, dtype: object
```

Check the [Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GxYJhX/1) and the [Python demo](https://regex101.com/r/GxYJhX/1).

Comment: I came across one text pattern that did not render as expected.. I have updated the original post with that text format and what was returned along with the expected output.. Is this something you can review if possible, thanks

Comment: The issue is related to the fact that your values can be enclosed not only in single quotes, but also in double quotes. I've updated the regex to support double quotes as well.